# Why isn't this method getting triggered by a @keyup event?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to focus a text field on <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> shortcut (in my Electron-Vue app):

---

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aqrBzq?editors=1010

The codepen uses [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#introduction) `v-text-field` custom component and as [this](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1587#issuecomment-326967711) comment on Github says, the method should be wrapped with `$nextTick` in order to focus this component

---

### Need this, but doesn't work

```javascript
 <v-text-field
   ref="filter"
   @keyup.alt.67="focusFilter" 
   label="type here" >
 </v-text-field>

 ...

 methods: {
   focusFilter(event){
     this.$nextTick(event.target.focus)
   }
 }
```

### This works, but is not what I need:

I also tried this code below, trying to focus it with a button, and it works, but I want to make it work with a key shortcut (for example <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> but more preferably <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, but for the sake of example I don't use reserved shortcut)

```javascript
 <v-btn @click="focusFilter()">focus</v-btn>

 ...

 methods: {
   focusFilter(event){
     this.$nextTick(this.$refs.filter.focus)
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're listening for a native event on a component you need to use the `.native` modifier.

So use this instead:

```
@keyup.native.alt.67="focusFilter"
```

Details here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

---

If you want to focus this input when `alt+c` is pressed and anything is focused you'd need to add an event handler to `window` for `keyup`.

I'd created a method to focus it under the right circumstances like:

```
methods: {
  listenForFocusFilterShortcut (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 67 && event.altKey) {
      this.$refs.filter.focus()
    }
  },
}
```

Then, add a created hook and attach this callback to the window when there's a `keyup` event.

```
created () {
  window.addEventListener(
    'keyup',
    this.listenForFocusFilterShortcut
  )
},
```

Then, remove the event listener when the component is removed:

```
destroyed () {
  window.removeEventListener(
    'keyup',
    this.listenForFocusFilterShortcut
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though it still doesn't work. Could you please check out the codepen, do you see any other mistakes there? maybe in the `methods: { }` ?

Comment: `this.$nextTick(event.target.focus)` isn't right, should be `this.$nextTick(() => event.target.focus())`. `event.target.focus` doesn't return a function like `$nextTick` expects. If you look at the console with the `.native` modifier added you'll see the invalid invocation.

Comment: It's odd that it gives me the "Illegal invocation" only when I focus the filed manually and only then press `ALT + C`. It's like it doesn't even listens for `ALT + C` until it's selected. What's the point of it then

Comment: You'd need to wait for that event on the window. A keyup will only fire on the "active" element then bubble up to window unless you stop it.  I'll add to my answer how I'd approach it.

Comment: Nice, it works now. Thank you for helping me (and potentially others) to understand it and for the provided example code that actually works!

Comment: No problem at all!